# How to create a react project war and deploy it on jboss?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, war

I know there are many articles on google about this but in some cases they are keeping react(frontend) + springboot(backend) together in a single war, but my requirement is different I want to keep the both wars as separate.

So what I tried till now,

1. Directly adding the react build folder in jboss->standalone->deployment but it does not work, it works on tomcat but not on jboss
2. Then I created a **new dynamic web maven project** and renamed react build folder and added it to maven project **webapps** directory and **created a war**, but after **deployment** its giving **403 error**, and I am not getting why.

Here is a snapshot of my **folder structure**, **pom** file and error on browser

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please help regarding this have been stuck at it for days now with jboss

**Is there any other way to do it, I will be happy to change my approach.**

tried this also, did not worked
https://www.megadix.it/blog/create-react-app-servlet/

Answer (score 1):

spring boot comes with default tomcat, you can exclude from the dependency

https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications

https://dev.to/jakmar17/deploy-spring-boot-on-wildfly-application-server-2029

Comment: I know about spring boot deployment, its react that is I am stuck with

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I haven't found a good solution. The best I found is to create a dynamic web project in eclipse. Copy the build files into webContent and use HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter with basename equal to the project name. Finally compile and generate the war. I hope the advice helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have now done the same thing.